# First of May in the future such that first of May occours twice between now and end

Tags: python, date

I'm running an optimiziation which should stretch between today and first of may in the future such that first of may occours twice.

E.g. if start_date = '2019-11-19' then I want end_date='2021-05-01' -> First of May occours twice.

If start_date = '2020-01-19' then I want end_date='2021-05-01' -> First of May occours twice.

But when start_date = '2020-06-19' then I want end_date='2022-05-01' -> First of May occours twice

How can I do this in Python? Basically I'd like to create an end_date that ends on first of May and also includes first of May twice in the range from today and end_date (including end_date)

Comment: What happens if the start date is the first of may itself?

Comment: Good question. If start_date='2020-05-01' then end_date='2022-05-01'. A full two year period @OferSadan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

```
import datetime as dt

def get_end_date(start_date):
    if start_date.month >= 5:
        end_date = dt.date(start_date.year + 2, 5, 1)
    else:
        end_date = dt.date(start_date.year + 1, 5, 1)
    return end_date
```

**Explanation**: If the date is in May or a later month, the end date is set to May 1st two years later. Otherwise the end date is set to May 1st one year later. Like this you will always have two May 1sts (except when the start date ist on May 1st, then you will get three May 1sts, as stated in the comments).

Alternatively, you could obtain the same result in one line, if you prefer that to defining a function. However, I find it less readable: `end_date = dt.date(start_date.year + 1 + int(bool(start_date.month // 5)), 5, 1)`

If you would also get the entire list of dates in the range as list, you can do as follows:

```
def get_date_range(start_date, end_date):
    delta = end_date - start_date
    return [start_date + dt.timedelta(days=i) for i in range(delta.days + 1)]
```

**Usage Examples**: Here are the examples given in your question

```
start_date = dt.date(2019, 11, 19)
end_date = get_end_date(start_date)
print(end_date)
```

Output:
2021-05-01

```
start_date = dt.date(2020, 1, 19)
end_date = get_end_date(start_date)
print(end_date)
```

Output:
2021-05-01

```
start_date = dt.date(2020, 6, 19)
end_date = get_end_date(start_date)
print(end_date)
```

Output:
2022-05-01

```
start_date = dt.date(2020, 5, 1)
end_date = get_end_date(start_date)
print(end_date)
```

Output:
2022-05-01

Answer (score 0):

Well the end date can never be more than 2 years away from the start date, otherwise there might be more than 2 of those. So we can start off with something like

```
date_range = [start_date + timedelta(days=i) for i in range(365 * 2 + 2)]
```

Because 365 days * 2 is two years. The `+ 2`  is to account for leap years and for the extra possibility that we start on may 1st. Now we just need to find the last 1st of may on that list and truncate the end of it.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def get_date_range(start_date):
    date_range = [start_date + timedelta(days=i) for i in range(365 * 2 + 2)]
    may_1st_indexes = [i for i, d in enumerate(date_range) if d.month == 5 and d.day == 1]
    return date_range[:may_1st_indexes[-1] + 1]

start_date = datetime.today() # This is just an example, put any other date here
result = get_date_range(start_date)
```

Example output:

```
>>> start = datetime(2019,5,1)
>>> my_range = get_date_range(start)
>>> my_range[0]
datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 1, 0, 0)
>>> my_range[-1]
datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 1, 0, 0)
```